# making a hotkey that does a specific command inside a program (autohotkey)

Tags: automation, autohotkey

Can I use AutoHotkey to make a hotkey that does a command specific to a certain program??? 
for example: opening the font settings in notepad

and if I can then how?
because all I seem to find is running a program or hitting some \keyboard buttons but can I do more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely looking for [WinMenuSelectItem](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMenuSelectItem.htm)

> From the docs: Invokes a menu item from the menu bar of the specified
> window.
>
> `WinMenuSelectItem, WinTitle, WinText, Menu , SubMenu1, SubMenu2, SubMenu3, SubMenu4, SubMenu5, SubMenu6, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText`

---

So for the Notepad font example, the Font setting is located in Format>Font of the Notepad menu. So, you could use something like:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad  ;If Notepad is active
^q::WinMenuSelectItem, A, , Format, Font    ;Open Format>Font of actitve window
#If
```

to trigger the command on Control+q if notepad is the active window.